# how i can fix the inside the chekbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I click on my page in the checkbox the inside of checkbox is changed. I want to fix for one element if he is empty will be empty for all moment.

```
<td class="pad30">
  <?php if($motifAbsence == 1) { ?>  
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if($isMotif = "Oui") echo 'checked="checked" '; ?> name="full"   /> 
  <?php } else { ?> 
     <input type="checkbox"  name="empty"  />          
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the checkbox readonly?

Comment: those are two different checkboxes, are you sure you don't mean one checkbox with a checked value on or off?

Comment: yes of course that's what i mean

Comment: @delboy1978uk  the first chekbox when he fond the element it is want make CHECK but when i went in my page i can the change this chekbox and be empty and i wanna fix this chekbox

Answer (score 3):

***1.*** You can add `onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"` for that purpose:-

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="empty" onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"/>
```

***2.*** You can use `disabled="disabled"` also:-

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="empty" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: @MarketLink glad to help you :):). Meanwhile please mark the answer as it solved your problem. Thanks